# How to Update Field Names Dynamically in SQL or SSRS Headings

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Hello I have a Record Set in this Manner:

```
                       2015-07-08     2015-05-08
Title   Description    
A       California       11              3
B       Florida           2              4
```

Now on the above fields of Dates, I need their Names Dynamicaly changed, like

if we have 2015-07-08 its in this week so I need 'This week Load' as Field Name Instead of Date, if its 2015-06-08, then its a month back so I need 'Last Month Load', if it is 2015-02-08, then I need it as 'Last Quarter'. how can I achieve this?

Please help on this, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (using dynamic query to change column names) 
 This isn't word for word but should give you an example.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP
(
    TITLE VARCHAR(MAX)
    , DESCR VARCHAR(MAX)
    , [2015-07-09] INT
    , [2015-05-09] INT
)

DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @QUERY = ' SELECT TITLE, DESCR, [2015-07-09] '

IF  '2015-07-09 00:00:00.000' = (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101)))
SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' AS [THIS WEEK] FROM #TMP'

EXECUTE (@QUERY)

DROP TABLE #TMP
```

PS: If you like this solution, please click on the tick sign next to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Headers are not so easy to achieve... You could 
1. try something with dynamic sql
2. try to find a solution with PIVOT.

This depends on how many different names are possible (only "This week", "Last Month" and "Last Quarter")? In this case you can create this names as part of your select within a CASE-WHEN and then use their caption as PIVOT sink.

I'll try to add a little exampel soon

Here you are:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE(d DATE,SomeValue INT);
INSERT INTO @dates
VALUES({ts'2015-07-08 00:00:00'},2)
     ,({ts'2015-07-07 00:00:00'},3)
     ,({ts'2015-07-01 00:00:00'},4)
     ,({ts'2015-06-02 00:00:00'},5)
     ,({ts'2015-05-27 00:00:00'},6)
     ,({ts'2015-03-17 00:00:00'},6)
     ,({ts'2015-01-07 00:00:00'},6)
     ,({ts'2014-05-27 00:00:00'},6)
     ,({ts'2014-05-27 00:00:00'},6);

WITH Today AS
(SELECT GETDATE() AS dat)
,dateBorders AS
(
    SELECT CAST(dat-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,dat) + 1 AS DATE) AS ThisMonday --please check this as it differs in cultures!
          ,CAST(CAST(YEAR(dat) AS VARCHAR(4)) + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(dat),2),' ','0') + '01' AS DATE) AS ThisMonthBegin
          ,CASE WHEN MONTH(dat) IN(3,6,9,12) THEN 2
                WHEN MONTH(dat) IN(4,7,10,1) THEN 3
                WHEN MONTH(dat) IN(5,8,12,2) THEN 4 END AS MonthsToPrevQuarter
    FROM Today
)
,dateBorders2 AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST(CAST(YEAR(ThisMonthBegin) AS VARCHAR(4)) + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(ThisMonthBegin) - MonthsToPrevQuarter,2),' ','0') + '01' AS DATE) AS LastQuarterBegin
    FROM dateBorders
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT SomeValue
          ,CASE WHEN d>=ThisMonday THEN 'This week'
                WHEN d>=ThisMonthBegin THEN 'This month'
                WHEN d>=LastQuarterBegin THEN 'Last quarter'
                ELSE 'older' END AS pivotMark
    FROM dateBorders2,@dates
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    SUM(SomeValue) FOR PivotMark IN([This week],[This month],[Last quarter],[older])
) AS p
```

ATTENTION: There will be some more fiddling around with the YEAR close to the year's break...

If you like this, please mark and/or vote up,thx!

Comment: Sure That would help, im trying the same as we are looking only for latest records all the rest fall in to prev ones.